# Grails install-plugin git Error

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

*Environment* 
**Windows 7, Grails 2.2.0/2.X, GGTS**

I have installed git on my computer successfully, I am now trying to install the Git plugin for grails using the command **install-plugin command**. I get the errors below, I have looked for a solution but have not found one yet.

Problems occurred (un)installing plugins. See details for more information

------System.out:-----------

| Loading Grails 2.2.0

| Configuring classpath.

| Environment set to development.....

| Warning The install-plugin command is deprecated and may be removed from a future version of Grails.  Plugin dependencies should be expressed in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy.  See http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/conf.html#pluginDependencies.

| Resolving plugin git. Please wait...

**| Error resolving plugin [name:git, group:org.grails.plugins, version:1.0-SNAPSHOT]. Plugin not found.**

**| Error Plugin not found for name [git] and version [1.0-SNAPSHOT]****

------System.err:-----------

Comment: Looks like it really doesn't exist in the Grails repo: http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/

Comment: Thanks - I am now proceeding to add it manually using grails integrate-with --git and regular git commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the `grails integrate-with --git` command instead

Answer (score 0):

i faced this problem when i was installing the searchable plug in but i figured out that my internet connection is through proxy so i got direct connection and it was installed successfully

Sherif

Comment: Thanks - the issue in my case seems to be that the repository location itself does not exist like doelleri mentions, at this point I configured the git stuff manually and it seems to be working at this point.